# How do I download (compile?) tar.gz2 or similar files?

Tags: compiling

I downloaded a tar.gz2 file and unpacked it using the package installer, but I don't know how to compile it. I looked at guides saying to find the README or INSTALL files, but I looked everywhere and I could not find either of these files.

So could someone please tell me what I can do?

Comment: what's the file and where did you get it from?

Answer (score 0):

The GNU Autobuild tools have been around for some time now and have become so standard that some packages are skipping the details in readme files.

First decompress the source code that you've downloaded. This will vary depending on the type of compression used. I believe your .gz2 file will decompress with gzip still.

```
  gzip -d filenamewithlotsofgobbledygook
```

I forget whether you will be left with a .tar file after that stage. if you see a .tar file then you need to run

```
   tar -xvf filenamewlogg.tar
```

at which point you should have a directory of source code. If it was made with the GNU autobuild system there will be a 'configure' executable shell script in the top source folder. Run it by typing

./configure

The system allows source code to work for many platforms and architectures and at this stage the script is looking at your particular systems architecture and OS and library qualities. If it requires a library that you do not have you may get an error and will have to install that library. This can get confusing because the keyword that the error gives is not identical with the package that you may need. For instance if missing header file you will need to load a -dev extended name. This can be an iterative process so each time you add a package you need to rerun ./configure again. If you get through ./configure without errors then you type

```
   make
```

and after that succeeds you type

```
   make install
```

to actually install the package on your local system, which is optional; you should be able to just run most programs from the directory that the source code is in.

Yes, this is complicated. However the system is very powerful and is one of the finest available. Once you learn these steps you will be able to deal with any source package so it is worthy of your time so long as you think you might need the skills again. Otherwise I'd recommend just doing binary installs. I'm sure this information exists in another location with much better detail, but this is my own rendition, leaving out details of low level driver libraries which need some extra attention. Ultimately when all goes well all source code works with the same three steps:

```
   ./configure
   make
   make install
```